# Warning #1366 on phpMyAdmin INSERT even with a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER code to resolve it. Natural?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

## Summary

When I use the phpMyAdmin GUI to insert a new entry into my table (which has a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER applied to it), it seems to insert the entry just fine... but it always displays this in response:

> ( ! ) 1 row inserted.
> Warning: #1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'line_id' at row 1

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to set up the trigger so I don't get the error?

## Background

*Note: You can probably skip the code blocks as you read.*

Using phpMyAdmin, I created my second table with this SQL statement. (This worked fine.)

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myDb`.`line_item` (
  `order_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `line_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `line_text` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`, `line_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_order_line_item`
    FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`)
    REFERENCES `myDb`.`order` (`order_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

You'll note there's **no** AUTO_INCREMENT imposed on *line_id*. That is because we want it to reset it's numbering with each new *order_id*. To accomplish this resetting number, we presumed a TRIGGER was most appropriate for the task.

When I tried to add a TRIGGER with this code, phpMyAdmin said it couldn't make it. (Something to do about "*permissions*" or such, but I quickly resorted to a built-in workaround after this little adventure.)

```sql
DELIMITER $$
USE `myDb`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `myDb`.`line_id_incrementer` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `line_item` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT;
    SELECT  COALESCE(MAX(line_id), 0) + 1
    INTO    i
    FROM    line_item
    WHERE   order_id = NEW.order_id;
    SET NEW.line_id = i;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

When the above SQL statement didn't work, I simply used the GUI of phpMyAdmin to add the trigger to the table.

Server:*localhost* > Database:*myDb* > Table:*line_item* > "Triggers" Tab > "New" > "Add Trigger"

**Trigger Name**: line_id_incrementer
**Table**: line_item
**Time**: BEFORE
**Event**: INSERT
**Definition**:

```sql
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT;
    SELECT  COALESCE(MAX(line_id), 0) + 1
    INTO    i
    FROM    line_item
    WHERE   order_id = NEW.order_id;
    SET NEW.line_id = i;
END
```

So far so fair.

Performing a practice run, I inserted a test entry into the 'order' table via the phpMyAdmin GUI (the 'Insert' Tab while viewing the 'order' table.): *No problems there*.

When I inserted a test entry for 'line_id' via the phpMyAdmin GUI, I left the NOT NULL 'line_id' field empty, to see if the trigger would fill it in correctly for me. And that's when I got this:

> ( ! ) 1 row inserted.
> Warning: #1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'line_id' at row 1

With the generated code shown as:

```sql
INSERT INTO `line_item` 
    (`order_id`, `line_id`, `line_text`) 
    VALUES ('1', '', 'This is a test line for the incrementer trigger');
```

What is *interesting* is: It inserted the entry as expected (with a 1 as the line_id). When I inserted a second entry, *the warning still showed*, but the next entry was also entered as expected (with a 2 as the line_id).

So, the rows seem to be inserted just fine, but I keep getting that nagging Warning which makes me suspect I didn't do something up to "Best Practice Standards".

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your trigger is that the`SELECT` query will not return anything if there are no rows yet in the table for the current order. One solution is to move the `COALESCE` to the `SET` :

```
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT;
    SELECT  MAX(line_id) + 1
    INTO    i
    FROM    line_item
    WHERE   order_id = NEW.order_id;
    SET NEW.line_id = COALESCE(i, 1);
END
```

Comment: I have rearranged the TRIGGER as @GMB suggested, however the same result appears to occur: The new row is inserted as desired, but the #1366 Warning still accompanies the insertion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your table definition is appropriate for what you wish to achieve. In particular the line_id and line_text are defined as not null. The problem with this is that the insert statement carries out the not null tests prior to the trigger being actioned and fails (I am assuming that your insert is only order_id and possibly line_text). You might want to look at setting default values. For example.

```
drop table if exists line_item;
CREATE TABLE `line_item` (
  `order_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `line_id` INT not null default 0,
  `line_text` VARCHAR(100) not null default '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`, `line_id`) #,
  #CONSTRAINT `FK_order_line_item`
  #  FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`)
  #  REFERENCES `myDb`.`order` (`order_id`)
  #  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  #  ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
  );

 drop trigger if exists t;
 delimiter $$
 create trigger t before insert on line_item 
 for each row
 BEGIN
DECLARE i INT;
    SELECT  MAX(line_id) + 1
    INTO    i
    FROM    line_item
    WHERE   order_id = NEW.order_id;
    SET NEW.line_id = COALESCE(i, 1);
END $$
delimiter $$

insert into line_item (order_id) values (1),(1);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

+----------+---------+-----------+
| order_id | line_id | line_text |
+----------+---------+-----------+
|        1 |       1 |           |
|        1 |       2 |           |
+----------+---------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I don't use phpmyadmin and have no idea why it shows the warning it does but I suggest you run the insert from command line sql to see what error it throws.

Comment: Ah. I see I have once again misunderstood the nature of SQL.  
I assumed a `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` would resolve, well, *before* an `INSERT` statement runs its constraint checking. [@P.Salmon](/users/6152400/p-salmon) was correct that adding a default value appeases the constraint check and thus circumvents the warning. Just ensure to set the default to an invalid value that can be easily identified... since this numbering starts at `1` searching for a `0` would suffice in this case.
Thanks for the insight.